# Adding a multiple left and right sidebar next to each using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Actually I have been trying to sort these out myself but I can't seem to figure it out, I have created a layout using flexbox but I am trying to achieve something. Let me state :-
I have a header, nav and a three column section that include, the main section and two sidebar at the left and right and I want to add more sidebar at 
right sidebar but I can't seem to figure it out since you know I have already declared the three column flex...

*You can check the image here for understand what am trying to achieve*
[image: U can check the image here for understand what am trying to achieve]

Source code here www.codepen.io/enipx/details/dQmXKP

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap two sidebar in right div .sidebarright

```css
/* ===== Framework ===== */

html{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
 -o-box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after{
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

body{
 background-color: #fdfafb;
 height: 100vh;
 /* border: 1px solid green; */
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
}

.col-1{
 width: 8.33%;
}
.col-2{
 width: 16.66%;
}
.col-3{
 width: 25%;
}
.col-4{
 width: 33.33%;
}
.col-5{
 width: 41.66%;
}
.col-6{
 width: 50%;
}
.col-7{
 width: 58.33%;
}
.col-8{
 width: 66.66%;
}
.col-9{
 width: 75%;
}
.col-10{
 width: 83.33%;
}
.col-11{
 width: 91.66%;
}
.col-12{
 width: 100% ;
}


/* ===== Layout ===== */

#header{
 margin: 10px;
 height: 90px;
 border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
 background-color: rgba(160,194,227,0.8);
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: medium;
}

#nav{
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 0;
 height: 40px;
 border-radius: 0;
 background-color: rgba(160,194,227,0.3);
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: medium;
}

.mainparent{
 display: flex;
}

.sidebarright{
 flex-basis: 16%;
 order: 1;
}

.sidebarrightfirst{
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 background-color: rgba(160,194,227,0.5);
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: medium;
 height: 195px;
}

.sidebarrightsecond{
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 background-color: rgba(160,194,227,0.5);
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: medium;
 height: 195px;
}

.sidebarleft{
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 background-color: rgba(160,194,227,0.5);
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: medium;
 flex-basis: 16%;
 order: -1;
 height: 400px;
}

.main{
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 margin-left: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 background-color: rgba(160,194,227,0.5);
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: medium;
 flex-basis: 68%;
 height: 400px;
}

.imgport{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.imgport img {
 width: calc(25% - 20px);
 height: 200px;
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 0;
 opacity: 0.8;
 transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.imgport img:hover {
 opacity: 1.0;
}

#footer{
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 0;
 height: 200px;
 border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
 background-color: rgba(160,194,227,0.8);
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: medium;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  header
 </header>

 <nav id="nav">
  nav
 </nav>

 <div class="mainparent">

        
    <div class="sidebarright">
      <aside class="sidebarrightfirst">
   sidebarright
  </aside>
      <aside class="sidebarrightsecond">
   sidebarright
  </aside>
    </div>
    
  <aside class="sidebarleft">
   sidebarleft
  </aside>

  <section class="main">
   main
  </section>
    
 </div>

 <div class="imgport">
    
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536276502222-b10f42bcf71e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=6266a66ab254251150d738aad585fd36" alt="boxes">
    
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538592716926-9a321f0614ea?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=488b23073a233d23083f36b67c3bd769" alt="boxes">
    
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506798161991-ff979d14a391?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=7378c40e370c1207c6bca0d269c81818" alt="boxes">
    
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1537203626302-cb08b9deb186?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=224379104368ef8280a06dfedda5c01b" alt="boxes">
    
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534256007535-8692ac6876cf?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=4c0f4f5d14175406c0ab97a8a0700950" alt="boxes">
    
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521405785232-7a56b029191e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=c15f44bf62d0a5307c50150953fea8deg" alt="boxes">
    
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521405785232-7a56b029191e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=c15f44bf62d0a5307c50150953fea8de" alt="boxes">
    
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534256007535-8692ac6876cf?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=4c0f4f5d14175406c0ab97a8a0700950" alt="boxes">
 </div>

 <footer id="footer">
  footer
 </footer>
```

Comment: Yeah, these works too,  Thanks a lot , I really appreciate

Comment: I will really appreciate if u can give me a link that explains more any flexbox thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Updated Codepen here](https://codepen.io/enipx/pen/dQmXKP/)
The idea is to wrap a column flexbox layout inside the right sidebar.

```css
/* ===== Framework ===== */

html{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
 -o-box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after{
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

body{
 background-color: #fdfafb;
 height: 100vh;
 /* border: 1px solid green; */
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
}

.col-1{
 width: 8.33%;
}
.col-2{
 width: 16.66%;
}
.col-3{
 width: 25%;
}
.col-4{
 width: 33.33%;
}
.col-5{
 width: 41.66%;
}
.col-6{
 width: 50%;
}
.col-7{
 width: 58.33%;
}
.col-8{
 width: 66.66%;
}
.col-9{
 width: 75%;
}
.col-10{
 width: 83.33%;
}
.col-11{
 width: 91.66%;
}
.col-12{
 width: 100% ;
}


/* ===== Layout ===== */

#header{
 margin: 10px;
 height: 90px;
 border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
 background-color: rgba(160,194,227,0.8);
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: medium;
}

#nav{
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 0;
 height: 40px;
 border-radius: 0;
 background-color: rgba(160,194,227,0.3);
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: medium;
}

.mainparent{
 display: flex;
}

.sidebarright{
 border-radius: 0;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: medium;
 flex-basis: 16%;
 order: 1;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column .top,
.column .bottom {
   margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 0;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
    height: 195px;
    background-color: rgba(160,194,227,0.8);
}


.sidebarleft{
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 background-color: rgba(160,194,227,0.5);
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: medium;
 flex-basis: 16%;
 order: -1;
 height: 400px;
}

.main{
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 margin-left: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 background-color: rgba(160,194,227,0.5);
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: medium;
 flex-basis: 68%;
 height: 400px;
}

.imgport{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.imgport img {
 width: calc(25% - 20px);
 height: 200px;
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 0;
 opacity: 0.8;
 transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.imgport img:hover {
 opacity: 1.0;
}

#footer{
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 0;
 height: 200px;
 border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
 background-color: rgba(160,194,227,0.8);
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: medium;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Layout</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

 <header id="header">
  header
 </header>

 <nav id="nav">
  nav
 </nav>

 <div class="mainparent">
  <aside class="sidebarright">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="top">sidebarright top</div>
        <div class="bottom">sidebarright bottom</div>
      </div>
  </aside>

  <aside class="sidebarleft">
   sidebarleft
  </aside>

  <section class="main">
   main
  </section>
 </div>

 <div class="imgport">
    
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536276502222-b10f42bcf71e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=6266a66ab254251150d738aad585fd36" alt="boxes">
    
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538592716926-9a321f0614ea?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=488b23073a233d23083f36b67c3bd769" alt="boxes">
    
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506798161991-ff979d14a391?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=7378c40e370c1207c6bca0d269c81818" alt="boxes">
    
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1537203626302-cb08b9deb186?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=224379104368ef8280a06dfedda5c01b" alt="boxes">
    
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534256007535-8692ac6876cf?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=4c0f4f5d14175406c0ab97a8a0700950" alt="boxes">
    
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521405785232-7a56b029191e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=c15f44bf62d0a5307c50150953fea8deg" alt="boxes">
    
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521405785232-7a56b029191e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=c15f44bf62d0a5307c50150953fea8de" alt="boxes">
    
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534256007535-8692ac6876cf?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=4c0f4f5d14175406c0ab97a8a0700950" alt="boxes">
 </div>

 <footer id="footer">
  footer
 </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Exactly So u give the sidebarright another parents inside the aside sidebarright and then u change it flex-direction to column and some CSS, then it works, Thank alot

Comment: I will really appreciate if u can give me a link that explains more any flexbox thanks

Comment: And try to remove the flex-basis: 100% in the 
.column .top,
.column .bottom class, the flex-basis is unable to make the height in it to have effect .. Thanks

Comment: No worries. Flexbox is quite powerful and a lot of frameworks are using it as well. @Hiren post a link from CSS Tricks and that article is pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for an answer to this question, here is my solution.

```css
/* all */
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.wrapper {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

/* Header */
/*header {*/
/*    display: flex;*/
/*    justify-content: center;*/
/*    padding: 10px 10px;*/
/*}*/
.page-info {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 3px solid black;

}
.page-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}

nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    color: royalblue;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* main */

.main-content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.main-content .vmist{
    /**  Задаём ширину 60% **/
    flex: 6;
    order: 0;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

/*.main-content .left-side{*/
/*    flex: 4;*/
/*    order: 1;*/
/*    border: 3px solid black;*/
/*}*/

.sidebarright{
    display: grid;
    flex: 4;
    order: 1;
}
.dodatok {
    background-color: orange;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
.footer {
    background-color: gray;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>
        <div class="page-info">
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="page-menu">
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu-active">
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#info">1</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#news">2</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#place">3</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#worker">4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="vmist">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebarright">
        <div class="dodatok">
            <aside class="sidebarrightfirst">
                right1
            </aside>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <aside class="sidebarrightfirst">
                right2
            </aside>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```